# rpy2 - pandas2ri.ri2py(df) isn't UTF-8 any more

Tags: python, r, encoding, utf-8, rpy2

At this moment I'm using rpy2, in python(2.7) to transform data (R is required)

```
from rpy2.robjects import pandas2ri
import rpy2.robjects as robjects
pandas2ri.activate()
```

Everything works great, but as soon as I want to transform my R data.frame object, after the r-transformation into a pandas data.frame Python object, I've noticed that it loses its UTF-8 format.

Thus at this moment, **r_df** is a r data.frame which might contain the next value **"Herpéto"**

```
r_df = self._r[function](p_df)
```

but when I want to have a pandas data.frame

```
p_df_2 = pandas2ri.ri2py(r_df)
```

The UTF-8 format is gone and I have a result like **"Herp\xc3\xa9to"**

Also, I don't know if a column is a string type, or numeric etc p_df and r_df can be anything

Comment: I have a much better experience with strings and encoding in Python 3 (with rpy2, and in general).

Comment: @lgautier - i've written an lambda function -- lambda x: x.decode("UTF-8") if(isinstance(x,  str)) else x -- but this doesn't do the trick;  it has transformed the data into : u'Herp\xe9to'   - But i've to upload my  data to a no-sql  thus, I won't print, or write it like in all the 100 tutorials